# SQL Server and Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am thinking about putting a SQL Server behind my Azure website. Is the sql server also free when using Windows Azure Websites?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Licensing agreements are off-topic.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Pricing is clearly documented on the Azure site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this is not a good SO question, but the answer is Yes and No.  Microsoft has offered a Azure Web App + SQL option that included a free small (20MB) database with your web app.  This was limited to one web app per subscription and the size and speed were so limited that it was really only useful for dev, testing and learning about Azure.  I would NOT recommend it for any sort of production unless you usage was super small.